# Using a single dummy argument for arrays of different shapes

Tags: fortran

Let's say we have several different contiguous arrays

```
real :: a1(2),a2(2),a3(2)
real :: b1(2,2), b2(2,2),b3(2,2)
real :: c1(3,3,3), c2(3,3,3),c3(3,3,3)
```

and a subroutine

```
subroutine mtpy(x,y,z)
  real,contiguous, intent(in) :: x(:), y(:)
  real, intent(out) :: z(size(x))

  z=x*y
end subroutine mtpy
```

How to use mtpy in the following series of calls:

```
call mtpy(a1,a2,a3)
call mtpy(b1,b2,b3)
call mtpy(c1,c2,c3)
```

Obviously, this is going to cause the compiler errors as the shape of the actual and dummy arguments do not match. In cases like these, I used to declare several specific procedures that each handles a specific shape and then wrap all of them using an interface. However, this is quite tedious (Imagine having huge amount of simple elemental function and pure procedures that treat multidimensional arrays (with up to three dimensions) as single dimension arrays and then providing instances such as sub_1d, sub_2d, sub_3d, .. for each of them despite all of them actually doing the same job).

One partial solution is to, I suppose, use RESHAPE

```
call mtpy(reshape(b1,[4]),reshape(b2,[4]),bb)
```

but, can I be certain that the compiler (I am interested in gfortran and ifort mostly)  won't start creating 1d temporaries to hold the reshaped b1 and b2 arrays?

Now, I am also aware that one can declare an array pointer such as

```
real, pointer, contiguous :: p1(:),p2(:),p3(:)
```

and make the following pointer assignment such as

```
p1(1:size(c1))=>c1
```

However, this approach has a drawback that I need to declare the original arrays as targets. Isn't this going to impact on the optimisations the compiler is going to be able to perform?

Yet another solution is, I suppose, to use assumed size arrays, but I noticed that Metcalf et al call their usage 'deprecated' and again, I am not sure about the impact on omptimisations.

So, is there a simple way of treating a multi-dimensional fortran array as a single dimension array (in a subroutine, or a fuction) which does not impose unnecessary assumptions (such as TARGET) on that array? If I can use RESHAPE without fear of creating temporaries (I am only dealing with contiguous arrays) I'd go for that. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you are treating a rank-1 array the same as a rank-2 array, then can you treat them as rank-0 and create an elemental subroutine?  If you are having to treat them distinctly then some expansion on why the shape isn't important but the array nature is would be useful.  [I wouldn't worry about assumed size, explicit shape being "deprecated": there are still valid uses and deprecation is just a view.]

Comment: @francescalus thank's for the correction! As to why I cannot simply use elementals, well, sometimes the output is not only dependent on the inputs, but on some external array-like data as well. Theoretically, I could rewrite the code to use elemental functions only, but practically it's not feasible. There may be other obstacles, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The future Fortran 2018 standard will provide assumed-rank arrays (that will allow to receive arrays of any rank) and a `select rank` construct that will easily allow to address situations like this with one assumed-rank array (see, e.g., [The new features of Fortran 2018](https://isotc.iso.org/livelink/livelink?func=ll&objId=19441669&objAction=Open&viewType=1) starting on page 16), and with more difficulty with multiple assumed-rank arrays.

Assumed-size arrays, while not fashionable or recommended are valid, non-obsolescent features of the current standard (Fortran 2008), as well as of the next standard draft (Fortran 2018), so they can be used if needed.  Since a lot of Fortran 77 code depends on this, and much of it is decades old, I would expect it to be significantly optimised in most compilers.

However, you don't need to use assumed-size arrays, you can use explicit-shape arrays (arrays with explicit dimensions), and as long as the array actual arguments have enough elements the code will be valid, since, according to paragraph 4 of section 12.5.2.11 of the 2008 standard,

> An actual argument that represents an element sequence and corresponds to a dummy argument that is an array is sequence associated with the dummy argument if the dummy argument is an explicit-shape or assumed-size array. The rank and shape of the actual argument need not agree with the rank and shape of the dummy argument, but the number of elements in the dummy argument shall not exceed the number of elements in the element sequence of the actual argument. If the dummy argument is assumed-size, the number of elements in the dummy argument is exactly the number of elements in the element sequence.

So you could

```
call mtpy(a1,a2,a3,size(a3))
call mtpy(b1,b2,b3,size(b3))
call mtpy(c1,c2,c3,size(c3))
...
subroutine mtpy(x,y,z,n)
  integer, intent(in) :: n
  real, intent(in) :: x(n), y(n)
  real, intent(out) :: z(n)
  z=x*y
end subroutine mtpy
```

Answer (score 1):

Because I'm also not sure whether `reshape()` makes a temporary array even for contiguous cases, I've tried printing the address of the original and passed arrays by `c_loc()`. Then, even for small 1-dimensional arrays, `reshape()` in both gfortran-8 and ifort-16 seems to create temporaries (because the address of the first element is different). So, it seems safer to assume that temporaries are created even for simple cases (for more info, please see comments by francescalus below.)

```
module test
    use iso_c_binding, only: c_loc
    implicit none

    interface linear
        module procedure linear_r2d, linear_r3d
    endinterface
contains

subroutine calc_ver1( a )  !! assumed-shape dummy array
    real, contiguous, target :: a(:)
    print *, "addr = ", c_loc( a(1) )
    print *, "vals = ", a
endsubroutine

subroutine calc_ver2( a, n )  !! explicit-shape dummy array
    integer      :: n
    real, target :: a( n )
    print *, "addr = ", c_loc( a(1) )
    print *, "vals = ", a
endsubroutine

function linear_r2d( a ) result( ptr )  !! returns a 1-d pointer from 2-d array
    real, contiguous, target  :: a(:,:)
    real, contiguous, pointer :: ptr(:)
    ptr( 1 : size(a) ) => a
endfunction

function linear_r3d( a ) result( ptr )  !! returns a 1-d pointer from 3-d array
    real, contiguous, target  :: a(:,:,:)
    real, contiguous, pointer :: ptr(:)
    ptr( 1 : size(a) ) => a
endfunction

endmodule

program main
    use test
    implicit none
    integer i
    real, target :: a(2), b(2,2), c(2,2,2)

    a = [1,2]
    b = reshape( [( 2*i, i=1,4 )], [2,2]   )
    c = reshape( [( 3*i, i=1,8 )], [2,2,2] )

    print *, "addr(a) = ", c_loc( a(1) )
    print *, "addr(b) = ", c_loc( b(1,1) )
    print *, "addr(c) = ", c_loc( c(1,1,1) )

    print *, "[ use assumed-shape dummy ]"
    call calc_ver1( a )
    ! call calc_ver1( b )  ! rank mismatch
    ! call calc_ver1( c )  ! rank mismatch

    print *, "--- with reshape() ---"
    call calc_ver1( reshape( b, [size(b)] ) )
    call calc_ver1( reshape( c, [size(c)] ) )

    print *, "--- with linear() ---"
    call calc_ver1( linear( b ) )
    call calc_ver1( linear( c ) )

    print *
    print *, "[ use explicit-shape dummy ]"
    call calc_ver2( a, size(a) )
    call calc_ver2( b, size(b) )
    call calc_ver2( c, size(c) )
end
```

Result of ifort-16 on Linux:

```
 addr(a) =                7040528
 addr(b) =                7040544
 addr(c) =                7040560
 [ use assumed-shape dummy ]
 addr =                7040528
 vals =    1.000000       2.000000    
 --- with reshape() ---
 addr =        140736361693536
 vals =    2.000000       4.000000       6.000000       8.000000    
 addr =        140736361693560
 vals =    3.000000       6.000000       9.000000       12.00000       15.00000       18.00000       21.00000       24.00000  
 --- with linear() ---
 addr =                7040544
 vals =    2.000000       4.000000       6.000000       8.000000    
 addr =                7040560
 vals =    3.000000       6.000000       9.000000       12.00000       15.00000       18.00000       21.00000       24.00000    

 [ use explicit-shape dummy ]
 addr =                7040528
 vals =    1.000000       2.000000    
 addr =                7040544
 vals =    2.000000       4.000000       6.000000       8.000000    
 addr =                7040560
 vals =    3.000000       6.000000       9.000000       12.00000       15.00000       18.00000       21.00000       24.00000
```

Result of gfortran-8 on OSX10.11:

```
 addr(a) =       140734555734776
 addr(b) =       140734555734752
 addr(c) =       140734555734720
 [ use assumed-shape dummy ]
 addr =       140734555734776
 vals =    1.00000000       2.00000000    
 --- with reshape() ---
 addr =       140734555734672
 vals =    2.00000000       4.00000000       6.00000000       8.00000000    
 addr =       140734555733984
 vals =    3.00000000       6.00000000       9.00000000       12.0000000       15.0000000       18.0000000       21.0000000       24.0000000    
 --- with linear() ---
 addr =       140734555734752
 vals =    2.00000000       4.00000000       6.00000000       8.00000000    
 addr =       140734555734720
 vals =    3.00000000       6.00000000       9.00000000       12.0000000       15.0000000       18.0000000       21.0000000       24.0000000    

 [ use explicit-shape dummy ]
 addr =       140734555734776
 vals =    1.00000000       2.00000000    
 addr =       140734555734752
 vals =    2.00000000       4.00000000       6.00000000       8.00000000    
 addr =       140734555734720
 vals =    3.00000000       6.00000000       9.00000000       12.0000000       15.0000000       18.0000000       21.0000000       24.0000000
```

And I also think that explicit-shape dummy arrays are useful depending on cases, and the code in the Question seems precisely the case. (Because the actual argument is contiguous, there is no array temporary created.) If the size argument `n` in `calc_ver2()` is not desired, we could use a function that returns a 1-d array pointer (see `linear()` above), but I guess this may be overkill considering the simplicity of `calc_ver2()`... (By the way, I've attached `target` in various places in the code, which is simply because `c_loc()` requires it).

Comment: It's no surprise that `reshape` creates something.  It's a function which returns a data entity.  A compiler would be required to do a lot of work to determine whether the created thing may actually be elided (note the halting problem).

Comment: I also think so, but I cannot find any web page that clearly states "reshape() always make a temporary" (though there are pages that suggest the creation of temporaries, e.g. https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-fortran-compiler-for-linux-and-mac-os-x/topic/597909). My understanding is that it creates a temporary, so avoid using it in a heavy spot or for large arrays. [And I think that using an explicit-shape dummy array is good here.]

Comment: I'd suggest that talking about "temporaries" isn't helpful.  We sensibly talk about temporaries in the context of copy-in/copy-out but the function result here is used in an expression (which is subsequently assigned to a variable, so some elision may be expected).  As an optimization a compiler may be able to just use a different dope vector but it has to be completely sure that neither `a` nor `b` is changed whilst both are in scope.

Comment: That said, in the context of this answer `c_loc(b)` is giving the C address of the variable `b`.  This isn't the same thing as the function result of `reshape`.

Comment: @francescalus Ah, I see... Because it returns a "value", it has to be an independent object (from the user side) from the dummy argument, even if compilers may do some optimization behind the hood... Then, is it okay to assume that if I see "transformational functions" (e.g. as shown here https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/RESHAPE.html) it returns a new object (at least formally from the user side), as in the case of transpose() ? [Btw, reshape() in some other languages sometimes return the original object "as-is", so I'm more confused...]

Comment: Yes, but you are also in a sense correct.  When a function is just returning something which is just a "different interpretation" of it's argument (also `transfer`) then there needn't always be a copy.  What, for example, happens with `MAX(RESHAPE(x,...))`?  Really, it's just down to how the resulting expression is used.

Comment: @francescalus Thanks very much, I think I understand a bit more. And one more thing is that, both gfortran and ifort do not report creation of array temporaries even if I attach various check options... but this is not related to the Question, so I will try asking elsewhere :)

Comment: Maybe you could try these again with `intent(in)` attribute on the `a` dummies?

Comment: @francescalus I've just tried, but no change... Another attempt is to attach -O3, but no change again. So both gfortran and ifort may be going in a safe (straight) way...